# Find array value that have dynamic key

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I'm having hard time figure this out , I'm trying to get values from mongodb document json object that have dynamic keys. I want to be able to get first  market like I'm doing normally with array like market[0] , from the json example I want to get like the first event name
and I'm trying to get it like that:

$market[0]['event'][0]['name']

I don't want to do for-each on markets and then for-each on event , I want to get exactly the value I need.
Thanks!

This is the way I can do it but I need better idea because there is hundreds of documents and it will get slow I guess.

```
foreach($document['market'] as $x)
{
    echo $x['name'];

        foreach($x['event'] as $ev);
    {
    echo $ev['name'];   
    }

}
```

```
{"market" : {
        "292044879" : {
            "type" : "some type", 
            "name" : "some name",  
        "event" : {
                "949157132" : {
                    "type" : "some type", 
                    "name" : "some name"
                }, 
                "949157131" : {
                    "type" : "some type", 
                    "name" : "some name"
                }, 
                "949157130" : {
                    "type" : "some type", 
                    "name" : "some name"
                }
            }
        }, 
        "292103762" : {
                    "type" : "some type", 
                    "name" : "some name" ,
            "event" : {
                "949334423" : {
                    "type" : "some type", 
                    "name" : "some name"
                }, 
                "949334422" : {
                    "type" : "some type", 
                    "name" : "some name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to echo the exact value I need as:

`$market[0]['event'][0]['name']`
or
`$market[1]['event'][0]['name']`

Comment: Maybe use of `array_column()` will help. [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) . Good luck!

Comment: You can use `array_keys()` to fetch the keys and use that array to get the elements by name.

Comment: i tried everthing allready :(